# Inserting multiple array items from table when checked

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I have a table populated from a mysql database.

```
echo "<td>" . '<input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date[]" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="time[]" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="note[]" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' value='{$row['mbrid']}'" . "</td>";
```

This creates a table with textboxes, the user can then tick the appropriate selections and submit, with the text fields then getting inserted into the relevant rows.

This isnt working correctly though, it seems to work if I tick the top few rows , but if I mix the selection its hit and miss what will insert. Not sure if its my loop?

```
   $date = $_POST['date'];  
   $time = $_POST['time'];
   $note = $_POST['note'];
   $select = $_POST['select'];


    $qry = "INSERT INTO bookings(mbrid, staff, date, time, note)
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);

    for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
    $stmt->bind_param('issss', $select[$i], $staff, $date[$i], $time[$i], $note[$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
    }
    $stmt->close();
```

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only checked checkboxes are posted, so the checkbox keys will not match the other field keys. So you need to link the checkboxes to the other fields. The easiest way is to set the key of the fields equal to the checkbox value (ie. `$row['mbrid']`)

```
echo "<td>" . '<input class="datepicker" type="text" name="date['.$row['mbrid'].']" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="time['.$row['mbrid'].']" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . '<input type="text" name="note['.$row['mbrid'].']" value="" />' . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<label class='checkbox'><input type='checkbox' name='select[]' value='{$row['mbrid']}'." . "</td>";
```

then you php code would be something like

```
$date = $_POST['date'];  
$time = $_POST['time'];
$note = $_POST['note'];
$select = $_POST['select'];

$qry = "INSERT INTO bookings(mbrid, staff, date, time, note)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($qry);

foreach($select as $key=>$value)
{
$stmt->bind_param('issss', $select[$key], $staff, $date[$value], $time[$value], $note[$value]);
$stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
```